# MATLAB 6.1 Windows7 Incompatibility Issues

Tags: matlab

I'm running MATLAB 6.1 on a Windows7 Home Pro laptop...

1. The MATLAB m-file Editor window has serious repaint issues - errors in repaint if window is dragged creates zig-zag window contents.  Minimizing and reopening window causes a repaint.
2. In the MATLAB 'current directory' window, file names do NOT appear, listed from the current folder.  This window view is always empty.  All other MATLAB windows (command history, workspace) are populated properly.

I have tried right clicking MATLAB.exe / properties,  and setting 'compatibility mode' settings to run in either Windows 2000 or Windows XP (SP3) modes, but no effect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Jim

Comment: It's a ten year old program, so I wish you luck. Consider an update if possible. Have you tried disabling all visual effects (in the compatibility tab)?

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB 6.1 sound like really old version which is not supported under Windows 7 anymore. I think you are out of luck and have to either

- Downgrade your windows
- Upgrade your MATLAB
- Use MATLAB in a WinXP VM

Comment: I would happily 'upgrade' to WindowsXP, but then I have to fake finding device drivers for all the laptop components, ugh. I cant run WinXP VM, without paying more to MacroSquish to upgrade 'Home Pro'.  And yup, MATLAB is 10 yrs old - so what? It does everything I want, I paid over $2000 for my personal copy (2001), and MATHWORKS wont let me upgrade, because I'm using a USA copy in Europe, where I now live. Terrible licensing policy IMHO.